# Convert tuple to concatenating the digits by recursion

Tags: python

```
def untuplify(tpl):
    if len(tpl) == 0:
        return 0
    n = 0
    while n <= len(tpl) - 1 :
        x += str(tpl[n])
        n += 1    
    return x
```

Why am I getting this error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment` ??

```
untuplify((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Should give me `12345`

Comment: Because obviously you are referencing `x` before defining it?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because in the line `x+=str(tpl[n])` your compiler don't know `x`

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no recursion here, you never call `untuplify` from within itself.

Second, the error message is because of the line

```
x += str(tpl[n])
```

You've never used `x` before, and now you want to add to it. That doesn't work.

Place a

```
x = ''
```

before the loop?

There are vastly easier ways to do this, but I think you're doing this as an exercise and aren't interested in them.

Edit: also, are you *sure* it makes sense to return the number 0 if the tuple is empty? Isn't the function supposed to return a string?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not initializing `x`:

```
n, x = 0, ''
```